# Where are URI/xml namespace information in xml/html documents located/defined?

Tags: uri

I was curious about the uri's for html/xml files which resemble "http://.../..."

For instance a web.xml file has this boilerplate stuff

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

So the uri specifies a web resource for the xml file that tells it what schema to use/etc right? Then what if you were to run this code locally without an internet connection? How would the xml file figure out what to do? Why do I not need to download all this stuff like I would need to for jar files instead of citing some uri? I mean I can use jstl tags, spring tags just by citing the uri. What kind of behind the scenes stuff is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for http, only for XML. The [W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#iri-use) says:

> The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, SHOULD have the characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists).

If the program reading your XML can't find the SchemaLocation, it will not check against that schema and probably provide you a warning. The XML itself doesn't know at all what to do.